adding bootloader as Loadable in Application file dont work if size of unified.hex is more than 100kb
i want some clarification about the size of unified hex file.
i have a simple blinkLED application which has along with bootloader unified hex file of size 16 kb.This worked successfully.
If switch is high than program resides in bootloader region and switch is low than program jump to application and LED will blink and if i add some than other application under 20kb(may b 32kb) using "btl_host.py" python script from microchip git repository than i am able program it successfully.
by using a unfied hex file of size 127kb, bootloader is accessable and working successfuly using above mentioned python script and python script worked successfuly but application dont work.
Is there any limitation of unified hex file size???
127kb application in stand alone mode work successfully.
Note:both blinkLED and other 127kb hex file have same linker script as follow
`PROVIDE(_vector_spacing = 0x0001);
PROVIDE(_ebase_address = 0x9D001000);
 
_RESET_ADDR          = 0xBD000000;
_GEN_EXCPT_ADDR        = _ebase_address + 0x180;

 
MEMORY
{
 kseg0_program_mem   (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x9D001000, LENGTH = 0x80000 - 0x1000
 kseg1_boot_mem       : ORIGIN = 0xBD000000, LENGTH = 0x490
 
 /* Bootloader Trigger Pattern 16 Bytes */
 kseg1_data_mem    (w!x) : ORIGIN = 0xA0000000 + 16, LENGTH = 0x20000 - 16
 
 sfrs            : ORIGIN = 0xBF800000, LENGTH = 0x100000
 configsfrs         : ORIGIN = 0xBFC02FF0, LENGTH = 0x10
}`


any body have idea what could be wrong???

The code was not working because of Configuration bit clash of CAN bus of both Bootloader and Application.
#pragma config FCANIO =     ON
by removing the clash worked. so application worked for bigger unified hex files also.
